# Chef run recipe on multiple nodes using environment or OS

Tags: chef-infra, knife, recipe, aws-opsworks

Is there a way to run a recipe on all nodes that fall into one environment? So far i see that i can add recipes to `run_list` but this affects only the node from the command. For example:

```
knife node run_list add  WIN-1GK0UP02HTV 'recipe[iis]'
```

How do i run this on all instances from `development` env? I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353595/how-apply-chef-cookbook-recipes-to-multiple-nodes) here that suggest that i can add one `run_list` to several instances. Is that an option? How is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not a feature Chef has. You can make a role and then add that to each node you want to target.

Comment: You would put that recipe in the role's run list.